# Solving a matrix with Crammers Rule in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to make a function where I can give it a matrix and the constants and solving it using crammers rule. This will soon be used with complex numbers.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as smp

def crammer(matrix, constants):
     D = np.linalg.det(matrix)
     dets = []
     dets.append(D)
     for i in range(0, len(constants[0]), 1):
          Dv = matrix
          Dv[:, i:i+1] = constants.T
          print(Dv)
          Dd = np.linalg.det(Dv)

          dets.append(Dd)
return dets


Mat = np.array([[2, 1,-1],
                [3, 2, 2],
                [4,-2, 3]])

Con = np.array([[1,13,9]])

print(crammer(Mat, Con))
```

I get this as the result:

```
[33.000000000000014, 33.000000000000014, 0.0, 0.0]
```

The first two are right the Determinate is D:33 and Dx:33 but Dy and Dz should be Dy:66 and Dz: 99.

following Crammers Rule it should be:

```
[[ 1  1 -1]
 [13  2  2]
 [ 9 -2  3]]
[[ 2  1 -1]
 [ 3 13  2]
 [ 4  9  3]]
[[ 2  2  1]
 [ 3  2 13]
 [ 4 -2  9]]
```

when I print Dv at the beginning of the for loop I get the following:

```
[[ 1  1 -1]
 [13  2  2]
 [ 9 -2  3]]
[[ 1  1 -1]
 [13 13  2]
 [ 9  9  3]]
[[ 1  1  1]
 [13 13 13]
 [ 9  9  9]]
```

I tried printing the matrix at the top of the for loop as well and I get the same problem. As I can tell my for loop is is changing my original matrix and I don't understand why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "and I don't understand why." Because `Dv = matrix` **does not copy** the array, it just gives the array another name. Please see the linked duplicate to see how to make a copy properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure what the algorithm itself is trying to accomplish, but from a Python perspective, by assigning `Dv = matrix`, you're creating a shallow copy by reference that then gets modified by the rest of the code in the loop.

I replaced this assignment with `Dv = deepcopy(matrix)` (use `from copy import deepcopy`) to create a deep copy, fresh from the original `matrix`.

That produced this result, which seems in line with what you predicted:

```
[33.000000000000014, 33.000000000000014, 66.00000000000003, 99.00000000000007]
```

[`copy` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

Comment: Hello, you for your help. its a method of solving a system of linear equations with complex numbers.

Comment: @ZachariahLoewen of course! Linear algebra was never my strong suit 